# Checking CSV data for integer then removing that int

Tags: python, excel, csv

Looking to break up and check individual cells from a CSV file that was pulled from Excel with Python 3.8. For example, I have a CSV file with the information `Honda 1, Toyota 2, Nissan 3...` I want to check each cell (not sure what to call the data before the comma delimiter) for an integer and then I want to remove it but also put it in its own cell. So the CSV would then read `Honda, 1, Toyota, 2, Nissan, 3...` The main goal would be to get those integers in a column next to the manufacturers in Excel.

I am pretty new to python but have some coding background. The logic I was thinking of would be something along the lines of, if char is int then add to new file else add N/A. My main problem is using the data in a csv file to do it. I thought about putting the data from the csv into a variable but the real csv file has over 20,000 cells so I'm not sure if that would be very efficient.

So far my code looks like this:

```
import csv

path = '/Users/testFolder/Test.csv'
new_path = '/Users/testFolder/Test2.csv'

test_file = open(path,'r')
data = test_file.read()

write_file = open(new_path,'w')
write_file.write(data)
print(data)

file = csv.reader(open(path), delimiter = ',')
for line in file:
    print(line)

test_file.close()
write_file.close()
```

Comment: Can you give a few lines from one of the files?  Or is it just one line with all of the entries?

Comment: Basically all the data is on a single line, if it was in excel it would all be in a row and each comma would be a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the parts of each item are separated by one or more spaces, you can do it a row-at-time (instead of reading the whole file into memory) like this:

```
import csv

path = 'remove_test.csv'
new_path = 'remove_test2.csv'

with open(path, 'r', newline='') as test_file, \
     open(new_path, 'w', newline='') as write_file:

    reader = csv.reader(test_file, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(write_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        new_row = [part for item in row for part in item.split()]
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: @ssumme: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful! So what this did to my data was add a comma after every word for example originally it was "Honda 1" now it is "Honda, 1" so now I just need to figure out how to go through the csv and whenever there is an int add that to a new file and if no int add N/A.